# How to web-scrape in in divs with DOMparser

Tags: php, html, xpath, web-scraping, domdocument

I am trying to get div and for other pages, trying to put it in a foreach. 
But facing some troubles,

```
<div class="article_info">
    <ul class="c-result_box">
     <li>
      <div class="inner cf">
       <div class="c-header">
         <div class="c-logo"> 
           <im src="/e/designs/31sumai/common/img/logo_08.png" alt="#"> 
             </div>
               <p class="c-supplier">三井のマンション</p>
                    <p class="c-name">
                        <a href="https://www.31sumai.com/mfr/K1503/" class="link" target="_blank">パークリュクス大阪天満</a>
                    </p>
```

I'm trying to get the text inside the `<a>` element, here is my codes, what I am missing here?

```
$start_id = 1501;
while(true){

    $url = 'https://www.31sumai.com/mfr/K'.$start_id.'/outline.html';
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $DOMParser = new \DOMDocument();
    $DOMParser->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($DOMParser);

    $classname="c-name";
    $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
    $MyTable = false; 
    $insertData = [];  
    foreach($nodes as $node){
        $allNames = [];
        foreach($node->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a){
            $name = $a->getElementsByTagName('a');
            $allProperties[] = [
                'names' => $name];
        }

    }
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Aside from the `while(true)` loop, this looks ok. What problems do you have?

Comment: I cant get `a href`s plain text... under c-name class...

Comment: You want the value of the `href` attribute?

Comment: Or do you want the text content of the `a` element?

Comment: i want text content of a element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on your XPath query to pull all the text node that you want, and then just get the `nodeValue` property within your loop:

```
$start_id = "1501";
$url = "https://www.31sumai.com/mfr/K$start_id/outline.html";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$DOMParser = new \DOMDocument();
$DOMParser->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($DOMParser);

$classname="c-name";

$nodes = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]/a/text()");
foreach($nodes as $node){
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: can u check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601528/how-to-web-scrape-dls-dt-and-dd-which-is-under-a-div-with-domparser-xpath