# How to web-scrape DL's DT and DD which is under a div with DOMparser/Xpath

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping, domparser

I am trying to get DL's DT and DD which is under a class and trying to put those in a foreach. But facing some troubles,

```
<dl class="c-explain2">
        <dt>所在地</dt>
                <dd>
                    大阪府大阪市　北区天満１丁目25番1（地番）
                        <br>
```

Here is my codes;

```
$DOMParser = new \DOMDocument();
$DOMParser->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($DOMParser);

$classname="c-explain2";
$getAllTable = $xpath->query("//dl[contains(@class, '$classname')]//");

foreach($getAllTable as $table){
            $allProperties = [];

            $table->getElementsByTagName('dt')[0]->nodeValue;

            $value = $table->getElementsByTagName('dd')[0]->nodeValue;
            $allProperties[] = [
                    'property' => $property, 
                    'value'=> $value];
            }
                $insertData[$start_id] = $allProperties;
                $MyTable = true;
```

How to get those dt and dd, After that want to put those in array. Any help? Thank you.

Comment: What is not working? I suspect you need to iterate over the inner dt/dd-nodes as well using `foreach`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your XPath expression, it should be `"//dl[@class='$classname']"`

Also it looks like you are never assigning `$property` in your loop. Try this:

```
<?php
$html = <<<END
<dl class="c-explain2">
        <dt>所在地</dt>
        <dd>大阪府大阪市　北区天満１丁目25番1（地番</dd>
</dl>
END;

$DOMParser = new \DOMDocument();
$DOMParser->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($DOMParser);

$classname   = "c-explain2";
$getAllTable = $xpath->query("//dl[@class='$classname']");

foreach ($getAllTable as $table)
{
    $allProperties = [];

    $property = $table->getElementsByTagName('dt')[0]->nodeValue;

    $value           = $table->getElementsByTagName('dd')[0]->nodeValue;
    $allProperties[] = [
        'property' => $property,
        'value' => $value
    ];
}
```